# The HPROF parser encountered a violation of the HPROF specification

Tags: mat

When I try to open a valid heapdump in MAT, I get this error. How to resolve this.

Error text:

```
The HPROF parser encountered a violation of the HPROF specification that it could not safely handle. This could be due to file truncation or a bug in the JVM. 
Please consider filing a bug at eclipse.org. To continue parsing the dump anyway, you can use -DhprofStrictnessWarning=true or set the strictness mode under Preferences > HPROF Parser > Parser Strictness. See the inner exception for details.
The HPROF parser encountered a violation of the HPROF specification that it could not safely handle. This could be due to file truncation or a bug in the JVM. P
lease consider filing a bug at eclipse.org. To continue parsing the dump anyway, you can use -DhprofStrictnessWarning=true or set the strictness mode under Preferences > HPROF Parser > Parser Strictness. See the inner exception for details.
(Possibly) Invalid HPROF file: Expected to read another 707,569,392 bytes, but only 69,932,894 bytes are available.
(Possibly) Invalid HPROF file: Expected to read another 707,569,392 bytes, but only 69,932,894 bytes are available.
```

Comment: Error says file was expected to be of around 700 mb. But looks like it's just 70 mb. Can you check the system where dump is being generate is not out of space?

Comment: Transferred the file with pscp and then opened. it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Changethe Preferences > Memory Analyzer > HPROF Parser > Parser Strictness from Strict to Warning

Comment: Change from Strict to Warning

Comment: This option is working for me :-)